# Converting .m file to binary executable

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler, matlab-coder

I need to create standalone executable files out of .m Matlab files. I have Matlab 2016a under university license. Seem I have these options:

```
1) MCR
2) Matlab Coder
3) Matlab Compiler
```

However I couldn't find MCRInstaller.bin on my machine nor I am sure if that is something that I am looking for.

Do you know which of these three options can help me and also how is the process of creating a binary file? Do these three also have free university license? If not, what are some tricks to create an executable using Matlab itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [Matlab Compiler,](https://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/) it will convert your m files into executable files for whatever OS you have.

MCR is matlab compiler runtime, it is required on the client side machines in order to run the compiled code (it is also free to download).

Matlab coder could theoretically be used to create C/C++ code that you then compile into an exe, but that process is fraught with errors.

Matlab usually will give matlab compiler licenses as part of the university package, I would check with your IT department.